# dpc_watchdog_violation. Am I safe? How do I fix it?

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, freeze, bsod

I bought a new ASUS screen (VN247) today and I'm using it together with my laptop ASUS N550JV. I made the new screen primary, and laptop screen secondary.

**Symptom**: This happened 3 times today while I was playing Heroes of the Storm and it never happened before. What happens is the game froze, I wait a bit and then I can alt tab for a short period. After that it freezes completely.

On the first two occurrences, I was also watching twitch while playing the game so I thought it may be the cause because it happened in 2 games out of 3 games (~30 min each). Later I was playing but there was nothing on my other screen and the game froze. So I waited this time instead of restarting the computer and got `dpc_watchdog_violation` BSOD.

I ran online crash analysis and the culprit seemed to be `csrss.exe`.

[image]

---

I googled this process, some say it's system process, some say it's virus. I expected it to be about graphics drivers but it appears to be about remote access.

My anti virus is on, my display drivers (or any other) are up to date. No unusual activity was going on on my laptop today, except for the new screen. So what causes this and how can I mitigate the further occurrences of this BSOD?

Comment: share the minidump files, please. Maybe we can see something.

Comment: Here is my [minidump file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4n2j4pn327uq7l/121414-8500-01.dmp?dl=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking it a bit, I see that the nVIDIA GPU driver is involved:

```
0xffffd000e1022cc8 : 0xfffff803c7e59e18 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0xa8
0xffffd000e1022d18 : 0xfffff803c7e56a71 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x91
0xffffd000e1022d48 : 0xfffff803c7f7172c : nt!KiIpiInterruptSubDispatch+0x7c
0xffffd000e1022d68 : 0xfffff803c7ef78f5 : nt!KiIpiProcessRequests+0x135
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys
0xffffd000e1022d88 : 0xfffff803c7f7172c : nt!KiIpiInterruptSubDispatch+0x7c
0xffffd000e1022da8 : 0xfffff803c7f714ff : nt!KiIpiInterrupt+0xff
0xffffd000e1022dc8 : 0xfffff803c7f7172c : nt!KiIpiInterruptSubDispatch+0x7c

Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
Timestamp:        Wed Nov 12 21:51:31 2014
```

try a different driver.

Comment: Do you have any idea why csrss.exe is involved in this?